# C#, WPF: Do work on each element in a list View

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app with a listview control.  The application basically loads a file into a list view.  I then want to iterate through each listview element, highlighting the current row, and performing a certain task.

When the task is done I update another file and a panel with the results and move on to the next listview element.

I've done stuff like this in WinForms before, but I'm quite green when it comes to WPF.  I guess my main concern is how to handle the second thread, other than the UI thread.  Is the threading model any different in WPF?

Secondly, the program is essentially a loop through an ObservableCollection:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < Collection.Count; i++)
{
   HighlightCurrentRowInListView();
   Collection[i].DoWork();
   PostWorkToPanel();

   // Bad loop around code
   if (i == (Collection.Count - 1))
   { i = -1; }
}
```

If I make a change to the collection (which is an ObservableCollection), how will the loop update?  Whats the best iteration method, foreach, .ForEach(x=>x) for this context?  The program should keep running until a "STOP" button or something is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need info on the threading model see the [respective MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).

Since you have an observable collection you can handle the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event, you can see if items have been added or removed so you can add or remove those from a workqueue that you could just take items from until it's empty (`while`-loop).

To change UI-Elements from the background thread you need to use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), see the threading model link i gave for help on that topic.